# Set Font Family and Font Size

Tags: fonts, fontsize

I want to set font family *Times new roman* with font size 24 pt for the title of a paper.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\title{Only this TITLE should be 24pt in Times New Roman font}
```

How can this font be set?

Comment: Can you compile with `xelatex`?

Comment: I use pdflatex.

Comment: And can you use a Times clone, or does it have to be Times New Roman?

Comment: It has to be times new romans or should be looked similar.
By the way, I have not used Times Clones.

Comment: Try `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}`. As for the font size, the command is `\fontsize{14pt}{17pt}\selectfont`.

Comment: @MasudShrabon - You should never adjust a journal's template! what is the purpose of a template, after all?

Answer (score 5):

Well, classically, you find the TFM file name for the font you want, assign it a control sequence, and then tell TeX what font that control sequence means.  E.g.:

```
\font\foo=bar12
```

You'd then issue `\foo` to start using the font `bar` in whatever size the file provided (in this case, the file name, `bar12`, indicates that it's probably a twelve-point font).

LaTeX2e made this all much easier with the New Font Selection Scheme (NFSS).  Instead, you can select a font in a number of different ways.  For example, to select Times:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
Now is the time...

\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont
Now is the time...
\end{document}
```

That will give you this:

[image: CM and Times]

The first line is Computer Modern (the default), the second is in Times.  The downside of this method is that you need to know the sometimes esoteric font family name; e.g., here Times is `ptm`, which is far from intuitive.  (The `p` refers to the foundry, Adobe; the `tm` means Times.)

For that reason, if you want your whole document set in another font, it's best to use a package designed for that purpose.  E.g., for Times, the recommended package is `mathptmx`:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
```

This will set your whole document to using Times, including math.

If you're using LuaTeX or one of its progeny, there's an even simpler way using the `fontspec` package.  You can use a human-readable name for the font using this system, namely whatever name the font uses on your computer.  To find out what those names are, run `luaotfload-tool --update` and then `luaotfload-tool --list=*`.  This will give you a list of all the fonts on your system that LuaTeX knows about.  So for my system, I found an easily-recognized one (Roboto Medium) and did this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Roboto Medium}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

And got this:

[image: Roboto Medium]

The `fontspec` documentation will tell you lots more; this is really a very powerful package.  Be sure, when using `fontspec`, that you compile with `lualatex`, not `pdflatex`, or it simply won't work; `fontspec`'s ability to use any system font is limited to `luatex`-based systems.

Comment: It also works with `xelatex` — actually, `fontspec` was initially developped for xelatex.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}


\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\title{\fontsize{24}{20}\selectfont{}Only this TITLE should be 24pt in Times New Roman font}


\maketitle

\lipsum{1-3}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That at least does the size.

Comment: If I use \usepackage{times}, will the entire document be times new roman?

Comment: Yes.  The answer by http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/59146/dgoodmaniii is more complete.